# Edge disjoint Hamiltonian cycles

Tags: graph-theory

The prism over Petersen's graph is Hamiltonian. Can you find two edge disjoint Hamiltonian cycles in this graph?

Comment: See Question 1 [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~west/regs/hamprism.html) for a reference.

Comment: +1 Interesting. How does this graph look like?

Comment: @draks: take two copies of the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph) and add an edge from each vertex in one copy to the corresponding vertex in the other copy. The result has 20 vertices, each of degree 4.

Comment: ahh, a prism, got it, thanks.

Comment: @joriki could you give me an answer in more detail, plz.. Thanks!

Comment: @newday: I can't. I don't have free access to that paper, and I don't want to duplicate the work they did. But it looks like you should be able to find the answer in that paper. If not you can always get back here.

Answer (score 1):

An example of the prism over the Petersen graph decomposing into Hamilton cycles:

[image: Hamiltonian decomposition of the prism over the Petersen graph]

A non-example (just to show that it's not always possible):

[image: Not a Hamiltonian decomposition of the prism over the Petersen graph]

Here the green edges are a Hamilton cycle, whereas the black edges are not.

These were found via a computer search.